# Is quintic equations have anything to do with their coefficients?

Tags: quintics

I was reading about quintic equations and this came up:

> In the early nineteenth century, Paolo Ruffini
>   (1765–1822) and Niels Henrik Abel (1802–1829) proved that no such general
>   formulas utilizing the usual operations and root operations exist. **This means that
>   there will never be a simple formula that provides the solutions for every single a, b,
>   c, d, e, and f in a quintic equation.**

so, I am a little confused. isn't the goal of solving a quintic equation is to find X? what is the role of coefficients in here? can anyone explain?

Comment: If you have no coefficients, do you even have a quintic to solve for $x$?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  It is, of course, true that $\textit {some}$ quintics are solvable.  $x^5$ for example, or $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)$.  The Theorem says that there isn't a "sensible" formula, akin to the quadratic formula, that solves all quintics regardless of the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

The role of coefficients is to specify which polynomial function is in the problem. There is no general solution in radicals analogous to, say, the quadratic formula; that's what the theorem is saying. (In the quadratic case, the formula writes roots in terms of coefficients.)

Comment: thank you very much. I did some digging and still have problems in understanding this part of the above context:  "the solutions for every single a, b, c, d, e, and f in a quintic equation." What is this mean? is the writer's intention is that for every arbitrary a, b, c, d, e, and f in a quintic equation?

Comment: @Daruissoli In other words, solving any problem of the form $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f=0$.